# Default alertView in iphone coming with out background color(iPhone)

Tags: ios4

I am using Default alert view in my iPhone  application in so many time .but it some times not coming properly ,its coming like with out  background color(its displaying only text on view).please help out me .
Thank you & Regards
  Narayana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this alternative

look at this url also http://kwigbo.com/post/318396305/iphone-sdk-custom-uialertview-background-color

```
Background of AlertView is an image And you can change this image



UIAlertView *theAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Atention"
   message: @"YOUR MESSAGE HERE", nil)
   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

    [theAlert show];

   UILabel *theTitle = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
   [theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

   UILabel *theBody = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
   [theBody setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

   UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];    
   theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
   CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);    
   [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];    
   theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   [[theAlert layer] setContents:[theImage CGImage]];
```